# How to load every page ahead while the service is still running?

Tags: angular, rxjs

For each page the user enters, I want to first render the page while the API call is still in progress and the service must run only once if it was a success.

I was trying to use the `resolver` approach, but the `resolver` itself is waiting for API call to finish and then render the page.

What I've tried:

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
    import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
    import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class HashCriptoResolver implements Resolve<any> {
      constructor(
          private googleAnalyticsService: GoogleAnalyticsService
      ) { }

      resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
      ): Observable<any> {
        const hashService$ = of({
          hash: '@$#@ERWWESDCFDSEWR@#@#'
        });
        return hashService$
          .pipe(
            delay(10000),
            tap(response => this.googleAnalyticsService.sendHash(response.hash))
          )
      }
    }


  {
    path: '',
    resolve: {
      hashId: HashCriptoResolver
    },
  }
```

The problem is that the `resolver` is waiting 10 seconds and then render the page.
Is there an another approach?

Comment: Please clarify/elaborate what you want to achieve. What is "the service" and what do you mean by loading every page ahead?

Comment: @Jineapple For each page the user enters, I want to first render the page while the API call is still in progress and the service must run only once if it was a success.

Comment: Then why not just trigger the api call from the constructor or ngOnInit of the page?

Answer (score 0):

> The interface defines a resolve() method that is invoked right after
> the ResolveStart router event. The router waits for the data to be
> resolved before the route is finally activated.

In your case I don’t think that resolver approach is a good choice because the resolver block the route until the data is resolved. Your request can take a long time to resolve.

Another approach is to use observables to fetch the data in the component itself and you can use loading indicator when fetching data. This can improve the user experience.